# Problem with useEffect and addEventListener

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, addeventlistener

I have the following code:

```
export const Menu = (props) => {
  const submenuRef = React.useRef(null);

  React.useEffect(() => {
    const onClick = (event) => {
      const target = event.target;
      const clickedOutside =
        submenuRef &&
        submenuRef.current &&
        !submenuRef.current.contains(target);
      clickedOutside && props.close();
    };
    document.addEventListener("click", onClick);

    return () => {
      document.removeEventListener("click", onClick);
    };
    // eslint-disable-next-line react-hooks/exhaustive-deps
  }, []);

  return (
    <div ref={submenuRef}>
      <div>I am a Menu</div>
    </div>
  );
};

export const Container = () => {
  const [show, setShow] = React.useState(false);

  const onClose = () => {
    setShow(false);
  };

  const openMenu = async () => {
    setShow(true);
  };

  return (
    <div>
      <div onClick={() => openMenu()}>
        <div>Open Menu</div>
        {show && <Menu close={onClose} />}
      </div>
    </div>
  );
};
```

In words, I have a sort of a button which shows a menu. Inside a menu there is an eventlistener which catches the clickes outside of the menu, in order to close it. It worked fine with React 17, now on React 18 the click which opens the menu is catched by the `Menu` component as well, which causes the menu to be closed.

[Here a sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/lucid-firefly-ufo8yw)

If I wrap the `document.addEventListener("click", onClick);` in a timeout, it works like expected: first click opens the menu, second click outside it closes it.

Why does the eventlistener catch a click already consumed? How can I fix it without timeout?

Answer (score 1):

Try using, `event.stopPropagation()`, this will stop the event from bubbling up to parent or child.

Answer (score 0):

The timing where useEffect is executed on React 18 has been changed (check out [this article](https://blog.bitsrc.io/react-v18-0-useeffect-bug-why-do-effects-run-twice-39babecede93) for more details).

So, on your `Menu` component you can try something like this to prevent double execution.

```js
  const execOnce = useRef(false);
  React.useEffect(() => {
    if (!execOnce.current) {
      const onClick = (event) => {
        const target = event.target;
        const clickedOutside =
          submenuRef &&
          submenuRef.current &&
          !submenuRef.current.contains(target);
        clickedOutside && props.close();
      };
      document.addEventListener("click", onClick);
    }
    return () => {
      execOnce.current = true;
      document.removeEventListener("click", onClick);
    };
  }, []);
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but I think this is more a workaround to the problem.

Answer (score 0):

The [event delegation](https://reactjs.org/blog/2020/10/20/react-v17.html#changes-to-event-delegation) model was changed, now the event a bubbled up to the root element not the document

Check for click event in the root element
// root element of the app
const rootElement = document.getElementById("root");
const root = createRoot(rootElement);

```
root.render(
  <StrictMode>
    <App />
  </StrictMode>
);

// in your component
  React.useEffect(() => {
    const onClick = (event) => {
      const target = event.target;
      console.log("target", target);
      const clickedOutside =
        submenuRef &&
        submenuRef.current &&
        !submenuRef.current.contains(target);
      clickedOutside && props.close();
    };
    const rootElement = document.getElementById("root");
    rootElement.addEventListener("click", onClick);

    return () => {
      rootElement.removeEventListener("click", onClick);
    };
    // eslint-disable-next-line react-hooks/exhaustive-deps
  }, []);
```

in the menu
const openMenu = async (e) => {
// prevent propagation
e.preventDefault();
setShow(true);
};

```
  return (
    <div>
      <div onClick={openMenu}> // pass the event 
        <div>Open Menu</div>
        {show && <Menu close={onClose} />}
      </div>
    </div>
  );
```

You can check the [Codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/lucid-neco-z9oc05so-z9oc05) to check the demo,
Hope it helps

Comment: Thanks, but how can the listener get triggered if it is set after the click event has been fired?